# How to create Hierarchy custom settings in Apex

Tags: apex, unit-test, customsetting

I need to create Hierarchy custom settings in my test class to avoid the seeAllDate = TRUE

Little confused on how to create Hierarchy custom settings. Looked at the docs and other questions but don't see one on how to create in Apex:

Below is how I do for the List settings:

```
    custSettings__c settings = new custSettings__c();
    settings.Name = 'SF Environment Settings';
    settings.someField__c = 'Some Value';

    insert settings;
```

Comment: if you created one via the UI - simply use data loader to export all fields and see how they are constructed.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use either of the two following constructs:

```
insert new custSettings__c(SetupOwnerId=UserInfo.getOrganizationId(), SomeField__c='Some Value');
```

Or:

```
custSettings__c settings = custSettings__c.getOrgDefaults();
settings.SomeField__c = 'Some Value';
upsert settings custSettings__c.Id;
```

Either way, basically you need to make sure SetupOwnerId is set to the organization's ID.

Answer (score 5):

To do this with a hierarchy you have to change the 'SetupOwnerId' so the entry recognizes the User or Profile to apply the setting to. As a best practice I like to put the label in parenthesis in the name because when you create one through the Salesforce UI itself it will label the type that way by default.

For a specific user:

```
    User user1 = TestDataFactory.createUser('Mickey', 'Mouse', Constants.SYSTEM_ADMINISTRATOR, Constants.SYSTEM_ADMINISTRATOR, true);
    //^^ this creates the test user and inserts them into the database temporarily^^
    CustomSettingName__c setting = new CustomSettingName__c();
    setting.Name = 'CustomSettingName (User)';
    //^^ Name input + hierarchy type^^
    setting.CustomSettingFieldName__c = false;
    setting.SetupOwnerId = user1.id;
    //^^ this line tells the setting which user it applies to^^
    insert setting;
```

For a specific profile:

```
    User user1 = TestDataFactory.createUser('Mickey', 'Mouse', Constants.SYSTEM_ADMINISTRATOR, Constants.SYSTEM_ADMINISTRATOR, true);
    //^^ this creates the test user and inserts them into the database temporarily^^
    CustomSettingName__c setting = new CustomSettingName__c();
    setting.Name = 'CustomSettingName (Profile)';
    //^^ Name input + hierarchy type^^
    setting.CustomSettingFieldName__c = false;
    setting.SetupOwnerId = user1.ProfileId;
    //^^ this line tells the setting which profile it applies to^^
    insert setting;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

For a test class, I like to simply upsert:

```
CustSettings__c settings = new custSettings__c.getInstance();
settings.someField__c = 'Some Value';
upsert settings;
```

The advantage being, is generally in a test class you don't care what the hierarchy is, you just care about what values your test class will be using.

If you want to test with a profile instead, you can always pass in the profile id to the getInstance() method. e.g.

```
CustSettings__c settings = new custSettings__c.getInstance(pid);
settings.someField__c = 'Some Value';
upsert settings;
```

The additional advantage of doing the upsert, is if say you set some of the custom settings in your data setup, and some in the test method, you'll get a nice automatic merge of all the fields you didn't override in your test method, and you don't have to worry about what if the setting already exists.